# Ext Js: show childrent element when parent is hidden

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to show children element as a part of parent element when parent is hide.
In practical terms, I need to show div when parent is hide.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. If the parent is hidden then the children will be hidden as well. You might want to explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ext-Js is a container, item system. So elements can only have one parent, if you really want to do this you can move the element to another parent that is visible on that action. Your better bet is to hide all items on the parent that you wish not to display, and not actually hide the parent